# Upgrading to Ansible 2.0 with Digital Ocean api v2 Issues

Tags: json, vagrant, ansible, digital-ocean

I have a working vagrant + ansible setup to provision my digital ocean, it was running on api v1, but when DO deprecated it I got an error message telling me there was no support for v1 anymore. After a research I found out I needed to upgrade to ansible 2.0 + update my digital_ocean.py since the older one was still using client_id and api_key, the new one however now uses the api_token.

Basically I've updated

1.digital_ocean.py which I got from ansible repo module
2. digital_ocean.ini to contain the api_token
3. updated my api token from DO to make sure it's using the new one

but when I execute my ansible playbook I initially got this error

```
ERROR! The file provisioning/inventory/staging/digital_ocean.py looks like it should be an executable inventory script, but is not marked executable. Perhaps you want to correct this with `chmod +x provisioning/inventory/staging/digital_ocean.py`?
```

So naturally had to chmod +x it but when I did I get a new error which is

```
ERROR! The file provisioning/inventory/staging/digital_ocean.py is marked as executable, but failed to execute correctly. If this is not supposed to be an executable script, correct this with `chmod -x provisioning/inventory/staging/digital_ocean.py`.
```

ERROR! Inventory script (provisioning/inventory/staging/digital_ocean.py) had an execution error:
ERROR! provisioning/inventory/staging/digital_ocean.py:3: Error parsing host definition ''''': No closing quotation

The next one seem to be json parsing related, my only problem is that it's on line 3 which if you check on the code itself are still on the comment side 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/digital_ocean.py

Comment: Run the script by hand and post the result.

Comment: I ran this python digital_ocean.py 

but got 
failed=True msg='`dopy` library required for this script'

It seems that dopy is not installed or seen by the system, weird thing is that I've already tried sudo pip install dopy and sudo pip install --upgrade but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I received both errors mentioned and solved them with the following:

The `dopy` related error was due to the fact that my python and pip were installed differently. dopy was installed via pip which was installed via homebrew. I was using the system python. When I installed python via homebrew, the script found dopy just fine.

Regarding the second error, that is the result I got when not setting the `DO_API_TOKEN`. I set mine in the command itself with:

```
DO_API_TOKEN=<api_token> ansible -i digital_ocean.py all -m ping
```